# Determining what zones are controlled by which thermostat

Tags: thermostat, heat, zoned-heating

I purchased a quad plex. We live in the double unit on the first floor and have one thermostat which seems to call for heat in our zone. On the second floor there are 2 units with seperate thermostats in each unit. Sometimes Unit 1 on the second floor does not get heat despite thermostatic setting. How can we find out which zones each of the 2 second floor thermostats 'control'? Did not get the info from prior owner unfortunately. Is there an approach you could recommend?
Thank you

Comment: What type of heat distribution & delivery? Hot water, steam, hot air? Radiators, fan/coils, radiant floor, ducts/vents?

Comment: Seems most likely that the zoning is as one would expect (thermostat controls the space it's in) but something (zone valve or damper) is intermittently faulty on that zone - or there's an air bubble in the pipes in that zone, or various things that depend on the previous question about how heat is delivered in this building.

Answer (score 0):

1. Grab a heavy sweater or sweatshirt for each occupant of the structure.
2. Set *all* thermostats to 60°F. Leave them there for a few hours to stabilize the temperature.
3. Set *one* thermostat to 70°F. Leave it there for a few hours. Walk around with an IR thermometer checking temperatures to see what areas have warmed up.
4. Reset that thermostat to 60°F. Leave it alone to all the temps to drop again.
5. Lather, rinse, repeat steps 3 & 4 for each of the other thermostats.

Be sure to record the results and commit them to paper. Put a laminated copy in the mechanical room(s) so that you don't forget in the future and as a courtesy to any future occupants.

Of course, if you have any of the walls or floors open, you could try tracing plumbing/electrical/duct work through the open walls, but I assumed you weren't at that stage or it may have been reasonably obvious.

Comment: ...or leave at a more normal setting and go up more (80F, say) when testing, which might tick off the occupants less. But there are probably much faster methods if the heat is delivered by a common method where you can feel (or measure) a hot pipe or duct.